# webApp on ipad safari close suddenly

Tags: html, ipad, web, safari

Im developing a html5 webApp for iPad and when I open it with Safari, this quit suddenly.
I'm using RoyalSlider plugin and I think the problem may be there since I'm using multiple instances but I don't know which is the specific problem and can´t solve it!

When I just use one instance there is no problem but I really need to use multiple instances of the slider.

Has anyone had similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

When a browser crashes due to rendering content of a web page it is a browser bug. Even if the content is invalid the browser must handle that.

I have no idea about iPod and iPad and iGod stuff, but maybe also on those systems there is the possibility to launch the browser from the command line instead of clicking a button? This is usually the first step to take when trying to find out why some application crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced crashing issues with iPad Safari and lots of large, hardware accelerated images, particularly on the first generation iPad. From a quick look at the Royal Slider homepage, it looks like they use hardware acceleration on iOS, though I don't know how they have it implemented.

When I encountered this problem it was because I was using a `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` effect to trick the iPad into hardware accelerating a div full of large images. The page would crash on load, but I was able to make it work by being more selective about which images I was trying to get the iPad to hardware accelerate at any given time. You might start by looking through the Royal Slider CSS to see how it's manipulating the images. Hope this helps!